# How I Put Data in Json FIle for a constractor property ? I get an error that Name ,Instructor, Credit can't access

Tags: c#, json, json-serialization

```
public class students
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string fName { get; set; }
        public string mName { get; set; }
        public string lName { get; set; }
        public string Dept { get; set; }
        public string Degree { get; set; }
        public _Semister[] ComplitedSemister { get; set; }
        public string SemesterCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime Year { get; set; }
        
    }
    
    public class _Semister
    {
      
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Instructor { get; set; }
        public int Credit { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 List<students> _data = new List<students>();
            _data.Add(new students()
            {
                ID = 101,
                fName = "Kamal",
                mName = "Hasan",
                lName = "Fahem",
                Dept = "CSE",
                Degree = "BSC",

                  ComplitedSemister =
                  {
                      Name ="dsg",
                      Instructor ="Jamal",
                      Credit =25
                  },

                SemesterCode = "Summer",
                Year = DateTime.Parse("2019-08-01")
            });
```

How I Put Data in Json FIle for ComplitedSemister property ? I get an error that  Name ,Instructor, Credit can't access. But Other property also accesss and work properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the appropriated object

```
List<students> _data = new List<students>();
            _data.Add(new students()
            {
                ID = 101,
                fName = "Kamal",
                mName = "Hasan",
                lName = "Fahem",
                Dept = "CSE",
                Degree = "BSC",
                  // Create the Array and populate with the object
                  ComplitedSemister = new _Semister[]{ 
                  new _Semister()
                  {
                      Name ="dsg",
                      Instructor ="Jamal",
                      Credit =25
                  }},

                SemesterCode = "Summer",
                Year = DateTime.Parse("2019-08-01")
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare ComplitedSemister as an array of _Semister:

```
    public _Semister[] ComplitedSemister { get; set; }
```

then you try to assing as a single object:

```
              ComplitedSemister =
              {
                  Name ="dsg",
                  Instructor ="Jamal",
                  Credit =25
              },

so it fails
```

I prefer using List when is possible

```
 public List<_Semister> ComplitedSemister { get; set; }
```

then

```
ComplitedSemister = new List<_Semister> {{
                  Name ="dsg",
                  Instructor ="Jamal",
                  Credit =25
              }},
```